# Drawing out of the screen and then rotate results in cutted view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view

> I've solved it. I have to use `transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }]` on the element itself otherwise it's clipped because `width: 100%, height: 100%` container.

I'm trying to do such a thing as "simulate landscape". So I want to set proper width/height (but it's not so important) and then I've tried to rotate the view. The result is quite unexpected – the view is cut.

For rotation I'm using:

```
 transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }]
```

Here is Snack repro:
https://snack.expo.io/r19t5yFif

In my real use-case, I'm using my native component, a component is aware of its size (as you can see on navigator) but it's cut away. I have been able to reproduce this behavior with plain Views as well.

Do anyone has and idea how to solve such a particular problem?

[image]

Comment: Fixed Snack  https://snack.expo.io/r1FELltjf , But Any specific reason why only simulate rather than actually switch to landscape mode ?

Comment: Thanks, I've just realized the same, it was because containers setting. 

To your question, the thing is that I can go to "landscape" in both ways, by rotating the device and if a user clicks in "fullscreen" button within a video. It's easier to rely on a source of truth that do magic on `onOrientationChange` handlers.

Comment: I would like to just set orientation to landscape when user presses fullscreen button and have the onOrientationChange get triggered . We have all fullscreen handling at one place.  What issues in this approach ?

Comment: How you can "set orientation"?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation but with this library, you can just "lock" orientation so then you have to solve where to unlock the orientation and thus you have to we aware when to lock it again because each of those operations will trigger the handler so you can end up in a loop.